# Fatal error: Call to a member function couponNC()

Tags: php, function, opencart, fatal-error

i'm using opencart

when i click link confirmation new member i found some problem,

this is message error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function couponNC()..line 23

and ini line 23 my code is

> $this->generate->couponNC($customer_id);

couponNC is myfunction in folder system/library ..

my file generate.php and my function is

```
    <?php 
     private $db;

    public function __construct($registry)
    {
        $this->db = $registry->get('db');
        $this->config = $registry->get('config');
    }

    public function couponNC ($customer_id) {
    // my function code
    }

    ?>
```

Help me to fix it.

Comment: consider uploading your real code. This appears it should be inside a class.

Comment: @KyleDomingo my fully source code i have uploaded

Answer (score 0):

This is my generated.php @kyleDomingo

```
<?php 

    class Generate
    {
        private $db;

        public function __construct($registry)
        {
            $this->db = $registry->get('db');
            $this->config = $registry->get('config');
        }

        public function couponNC ($customer_id) {
            $customer = $this->getCustomer($customer_id);
            if(isset($customer['firstname'])){
                $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET approved = '1' WHERE customer_id='" . $customer_id . "'");
                $date_add =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $date_start =  date("Y-m-d");
                $date_end =  date("Y-m-d", mktime(date("H"),date("i"),date("s"),date("m"),date("d")+30,date("Y")));
                    $length = '5';
                    $random = strtoupper(crypt(uniqid(rand(),1))); 
                    $random_no_slashes = strip_tags(stripslashes($random));
                    $random_id = str_replace(".","",$random_no_slashes); 
                    $random_final = strrev(str_replace("/","",$random_id));
                    $random_use = "NC".substr($random_final,0,$length); 
                    //$kupon .= "Random Id: $random_use<br>" ;
                    $counpons[]=array(
                        'code'  => $random_use
                    );
                    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "coupon`  SET name = 'Coupon New Customer', code = '".$random_use."', type = 'F', discount = '50000', logged = '0', shipping = '0', total = '150000', date_start = '".$date_start."', date_end = '".$date_end."', uses_total = '1', uses_customer = '1', status = '1', date_added = '".$date_add."', discount_type = 'A', one_product = '0'");
                    /*, product_not_include = '1'*/

                    $lastId = $this->db->getLastId();

                    $categories = array('43','206');
                    foreach($categories as $category){
                        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "coupon_category` SET coupon_id = '".$lastId."', category_id = '".$category."'");
                    }
    $no = 1;
    $html = ''
          foreach($counpons as $coupon){ 
            $html .= '    <tr>
                    <td class="left">'.$no.'</td>
                    <td class="left">'.$coupon['code'].'</td>
                    <td class="right">Rp. 50.000</td>
                  </tr>';
                  $no++;
                  } 
    $html .= '';
            //echo $html;die;
            $this->sendMail("domain.com Gift Voucher. Just For You!",$html,$customer['email']);
                    }
        }

        public function getOrder($order_id) {
            $order_query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, (SELECT os.name FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_status` os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = o.language_id) AS order_status FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o WHERE o.order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");

            if ($order_query->num_rows) {
                $country_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "country` WHERE country_id = '" . (int)$order_query->row['payment_country_id'] . "'");

                if ($country_query->num_rows) {
                    $payment_iso_code_2 = $country_query->row['iso_code_2'];
                    $payment_iso_code_3 = $country_query->row['iso_code_3'];
                } else {
                    $payment_iso_code_2 = '';
                    $payment_iso_code_3 = '';
                }

                $zone_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "zone` WHERE zone_id = '" . (int)$order_query->row['payment_zone_id'] . "'");

                if ($zone_query->num_rows) {
                    $payment_zone_code = $zone_query->row['code'];
                } else {
                    $payment_zone_code = '';
                }


                $country_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "country` WHERE country_id = '" . (int)$order_query->row['shipping_country_id'] . "'");

                if ($country_query->num_rows) {
                    $shipping_iso_code_2 = $country_query->row['iso_code_2'];
                    $shipping_iso_code_3 = $country_query->row['iso_code_3'];
                } else {
                    $shipping_iso_code_2 = '';
                    $shipping_iso_code_3 = '';
                }

                $zone_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "zone` WHERE zone_id = '" . (int)$order_query->row['shipping_zone_id'] . "'");

                if ($zone_query->num_rows) {
                    $shipping_zone_code = $zone_query->row['code'];
                } else {
                    $shipping_zone_code = '';
                }

                return array(
                    'order_id'                => $order_query->row['order_id'],
                    'invoice_no'              => $order_query->row['invoice_no'],
                    'invoice_prefix'          => $order_query->row['invoice_prefix'],
                    'store_id'                => $order_query->row['store_id'],
                    'store_name'              => $order_query->row['store_name'],
                    'store_url'               => $order_query->row['store_url'],
                    'customer_id'             => $order_query->row['customer_id'],
                    'firstname'               => $order_query->row['firstname'],
                    'lastname'                => $order_query->row['lastname'],
                    'telephone'               => $order_query->row['telephone'],
                    'fax'                     => $order_query->row['fax'],
                    'email'                   => $order_query->row['email'],
                    'payment_firstname'       => $order_query->row['payment_firstname'],
                    'payment_lastname'        => $order_query->row['payment_lastname'],
                    'payment_company'         => $order_query->row['payment_company'],
                    'payment_company_id'      => $order_query->row['payment_company_id'],
                    'payment_tax_id'          => $order_query->row['payment_tax_id'],
                    'payment_address_1'       => $order_query->row['payment_address_1'],
                    'payment_address_2'       => $order_query->row['payment_address_2'],
                    'payment_postcode'        => $order_query->row['payment_postcode'],
                    'payment_city'            => $order_query->row['payment_city'],
                    'payment_zone_id'         => $order_query->row['payment_zone_id'],
                    'payment_zone'            => $order_query->row['payment_zone'],
                    'payment_zone_code'       => $payment_zone_code,
                    'payment_country_id'      => $order_query->row['payment_country_id'],
                    'payment_country'         => $order_query->row['payment_country'],
                    'payment_iso_code_2'      => $payment_iso_code_2,
                    'payment_iso_code_3'      => $payment_iso_code_3,
                    'payment_address_format'  => $order_query->row['payment_address_format'],
                    'payment_method'          => $order_query->row['payment_method'],
                    'payment_code'            => $order_query->row['payment_code'],
                    'shipping_firstname'      => $order_query->row['shipping_firstname'],
                    'shipping_lastname'       => $order_query->row['shipping_lastname'],
                    'shipping_company'        => $order_query->row['shipping_company'],
                    'shipping_address_1'      => $order_query->row['shipping_address_1'],
                    'shipping_address_2'      => $order_query->row['shipping_address_2'],
                    'shipping_postcode'       => $order_query->row['shipping_postcode'],
                    'shipping_district'       => $order_query->row['shipping_district'],
                    'shipping_city'           => $order_query->row['shipping_city'],
                    'shipping_zone_id'        => $order_query->row['shipping_zone_id'],
                    'shipping_zone'           => $order_query->row['shipping_zone'],
                    'shipping_zone_code'      => $shipping_zone_code,
                    'shipping_country_id'     => $order_query->row['shipping_country_id'],
                    'shipping_country'        => $order_query->row['shipping_country'],
                    'shipping_iso_code_2'     => $shipping_iso_code_2,
                    'shipping_iso_code_3'     => $shipping_iso_code_3,
                    'shipping_address_format' => $order_query->row['shipping_address_format'],
                    'shipping_method'         => $order_query->row['shipping_method'],
                    'shipping_code'           => $order_query->row['shipping_code'],
                    'comment'                 => $order_query->row['comment'],
                    'total'                   => $order_query->row['total'],
                    'order_status_id'         => $order_query->row['order_status_id'],
                    'order_status'            => $order_query->row['order_status'],
                    'currency_id'             => $order_query->row['currency_id'],
                    'currency_code'           => $order_query->row['currency_code'],
                    'currency_value'          => $order_query->row['currency_value'],
                    'ip'                      => $order_query->row['ip'],
                    'senddata'                => $order_query->row['senddata'],
                    'forwarded_ip'            => $order_query->row['forwarded_ip'],
                    'user_agent'              => $order_query->row['user_agent'],
                    'accept_language'         => $order_query->row['accept_language'],
                    'date_modified'           => $order_query->row['date_modified'],
                    'installment'             => $order_query->row['installment'],
                    'weight'                  => $order_query->row['weight'],
                    'card_discount_id'        => $order_query->row['card_discount_id'],
                    'lazada_order'            => $order_query->row['lazada_order'],
                    'date_added'              => date("d.m.Y H:i:s", strtotime($order_query->row['date_added']))
                );
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public function getOrderProducts($order_id) {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");

            return $query->rows;
        }

        public function getTotal($order_id,$code){
            $query = $this->db->query("select * from `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_total` where order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' and code='$code'");
            return $query->row;
        }

        public function getOrderCoupon($order_id) {
            $query = $this->db->query("Select * from (
            SELECT amount,coupon_id FROM `cartcoupon_history` WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'
            ) ch
            left join 
            (
            SELECT code,coupon_id,`name` as nama,type,discount FROM `cartcoupon`
            ) c 
            on c.coupon_id=ch.coupon_id");
            return $query->rows;
        }
        public function getCustomer($customer_id) {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "' AND approved = '0'");

            return $query->row;
        }
        public function getLogVoucher($order_id){
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM log_voucher WHERE order_id = '" . $order_id . "'");

            return $query->row;
        }
        public function sendMail($subject,$message,$to){
            $mail = new Mail();
            $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
            $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
            $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
            $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
            $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
            $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
            $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');
            $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
            $mail->setSender("/*my domain*/");
            $mail->setSubject($subject);
            //$mail->setText($message);
            $mail->setHtml($message);
            $mail->setTo($to);
            $mail->send();
        }

    }

    ?>
```